# What's the tense in this sentence? Or is it incorrect

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical

Here is an abstract from an email:

> J'aurais mis du temps à écrire ces mots.

which, in context, means "*It took me some time to write these words*".

However, the only "*j'aurais*" that appears on [this conjugator](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/auxiliaire/avoir/) is the "Conditional tense", which doesn't match the meaning aforementioned.

Is this a mistake on the part of the poster?

Comment: What is "an abstract from an email"? :it took me some time to" = Cela m'a pris un bon moment pour faire x and is not what the French sentence says **at all**.

Comment: Please post more of that email than this single sentence. Your translation doesn't match what is written, but there might be a typo in the French verb too. That makes too many uncertainties to expect definitive answers.

Answer (score 3):

C'est une expression que l'on entend parfois effectivement (plutôt à l'oral donc)

> J'aurais mis du temps à...

Qu'elle soit utilisée ne veut pas dire qu'elle est correcte bien sûr. Un avis catégorique ne me paraît pas évident.

Le conditionnel passé a une valeur de futur dans le passé. Il permet ainsi d'imaginer des situations irréelles dans le passé, et donc par exemple d'exprimer des regrets :

> Nous aurions aimé aller voir un film, mais les cinémas étaient fermés.

Dans la phrase *j'aurais mis du temps à ...*, l'auteur exprime un regret, de n'avoir pas écrit plus tôt.

Dans la mesure où la situation n'est pas irréelle, l'auteur a effectivement trop tardé, on peut défendre l'idée qu'il aurait été préférable d'écrire :

> J'ai mis du temps à ...

Mais dans ce cas, le regret n'est pas exprimé, le sens est différent ...

Answer (score 2):

Not native speaker. Actually the translation is

> I would have taken a long time to write these words.

That is

> J'aurais mis

is the conditionnel passé.

I am not sure about the desired meaning without more information about the received message. Based on

https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/conditionnel.php

I think it could convey a protestation. Only a native could verify though.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in this sentence; instead of "aurais", which shows a conditional, "aurai" must be used, and the tense that results is not the "conditionnel passé" but the "futur antérieur de l'indicatif".

In your sentence, its value is modal and it is used to formulate an assessment (in French, "un bilan") ([ref.,Podcast Français Facile, II 4](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/cours/futur-anterieur.html)).

> Exemples :     Ça aura été difficile, mais nous y serons arrivés !

The sentence is still not idiomatic, however; in French you must add a pronoun ("en"). Here is the idiomatic form. The punctuation at the end can be a full stop but it can also be suspension points or an exclamation point.

- J'**en** aurai mis du temps à écrire ces mots.

Comment: Depending on the context, this sentence could be correct, though, couldn't it? As in : "Imagine que je sois manchot. J'aurais mis du temps à écrire ces mots."